# Could not find a distribution template for Kali/kali-rolling :gns3 installation?

Tags: apt, sudo, kali-linux, repository

I am trying to setup GNS3 on kali  using

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gns3/ppa

But receive the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 95, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 93, in get_sources
    (self.id, self.codename))
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Kali/kali-rolling
```

Comment: http://ppa.launchpad.net/gns3/ppa/ubuntu ... is Ubuntu only ! http://ppa.launchpad.net/gns3/ppa/ubuntu/dists/

Comment: @KnudLarsen , for kali  how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for kali how to do it

You can download the latest packages ( March 2018 updated ) https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1in6S35GpPGvge5t_2B-36_X_uDJuxX2x?usp=sharing ... and install in this sequence :

```
cd Downloads/
apt install gns3/ubridge_0.9.14-1~xenial1_amd64.deb
apt install gns3/gns3-server_2.1.4~xenial1_amd64.deb
apt install gns3/gns3-gui_2.1.4~xenial1_amd64.deb
apt install gns3/vpcs_0.6.1-1~xenial1_amd64.deb
apt install gns3/dynamips_0.2.17-1~xenial1_amd64.deb

dpkg --add-architecture i386
gdebi gns3/iouyap_0.97-1~xenial3_amd64.deb
gdebi libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb7u4_i386.deb   // from oldoldstable Wheezy →
```

→ http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb7u4_i386.deb

```
gdebi gns3/gns3-iou_0.0.1~xenial2_amd64.deb
```

( I made the test install with Debian 9 Stretch.)

Updates : Please have a look here once a month http://ppa.launchpad.net/gns3/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/ ... if you want the latest packages.

Comment: Whats does the Distribution Template Error Signifies?

Comment: `NoDistroTemplateException` means: You are **not** on this Ubuntu list ! http://ppa.launchpad.net/gns3/ppa/ubuntu/dists/ ... ... Where **Distro** means "Linux OS".